How to properly close a WebSocket connection after running an asynchronous function in Python?
I am running into this problem where the websocket will not close after I run an asynchronous function that asks for input ( i think its interrupting the main event loop or something).This code is just a recreation of the same problem that I ran into in my actual project where the "second function" actually runs a textual application but after i quit the app i cant get the connection to close. For some reason when I get to the "await websocket.close()" line it pauses and then times out without closing it.
import asyncio
import websockets

async def connect_and_send(ip, port):
    uri = f"ws://{ip}:{port}"
    websocket = await websockets.connect(uri)
    # Send a message (optional)
    await websocket.send(r"C:\Volgistics\Vlogger;Boi.txt;;None")
    print("Message sent.")

    # Call the second function
    await second_function(websocket)

    # Close the connection
    print("Closing the connection...")
    await websocket.close()

async def second_function(websocket):
    # Perform some operations or send additional messages
    input("Press Enter to send additional message...")
    if input:
        await websocket.send(r"C:\Volgistics\Vlogger;Boi.txt;second;None")
    
    print("Additional message sent.")

    # You can add more operations or logic here

# Replace with your desired IP and port
ip = "192.168.3.181"
port = 8888

asyncio.run(connect_and_send(ip, port))

I've tried various approaches, such as using threading.Thread to run the asynchronous function in a separate thread, creating a new event loop within the thread, and awaiting the websocket.close() operation in the main event loop. However, I'm still unable to close the WebSocket connection properly after the asynchronous function completes.
My goal is to ensure that the WebSocket connection is closed cleanly after the asynchronous function finishes executing. This is a simplified example, but I'm facing a similar issue in my actual project.
Can someone please help me understand what I'm doing wrong and provide a solution to properly close the WebSocket connection in this scenario?

Use context instead of closing websockets manually: with connect(uri) as websocket: ...

As mentioned in Johnny's comment, using a context manager is a much cleaner way of doing this.
This is quite simple to implement and I will show you how.
When using context managers, you don't need to close the websocket, it just does it itself. This is the same when opening/closing files. To do this in your code, you would just remove close call and replace the connect call with with websockets.connect(uri) as websocket: and then go into your code.
This would look something like this:
import asyncio
import websockets

async def connect_and_send(ip, port):
    uri = f"ws://{ip}:{port}"

    # VVV Changed websockets.connect to use a context manager

    async with websockets.connect(uri) as websocket:
        # Send a message (optional)
        await websocket.send(r"C:\Volgistics\Vlogger;Boi.txt;;None")
        print("Message sent.")

        # Call the second function
        await second_function(websocket)

        # Close the connection
        print("Closing the connection...")
        
        # ^^^ No websocket.close

async def second_function(websocket):
    # Perform some operations or send additional messages
    input("Press Enter to send additional message...")
    if input:
        await websocket.send(r"C:\Volgistics\Vlogger;Boi.txt;second;None")
    
    print("Additional message sent.")

    # You can add more operations or logic here

# Replace with your desired IP and port
ip = "192.168.3.181"
port = 8888

asyncio.run(connect_and_send(ip, port))

Like I said before, no close call is necessary here as it does it for you.
Hope this helps!
